# C - Alphabetically sorting arrays error

Tags: c, arrays, sorting, structure

I'm working on a phone book assignment for my CECS class and I ran into a problem with alphabetically sorting the contacts. The program will allow me to sort up to 3 contacts, however when I try to sort more than 3, the program starts spitting out garbage variables and possibly crashing.

```
void Sort(phone *phonebook, int *num_entries)
{
 int tracker = *num_entries;
 if (tracker >= 0)
 {
 phone *temp = (phone*) calloc(tracker, sizeof(phone));
 if (temp== NULL)
    printf("\n\nOut of memory\n\n");
 else
 {
 int i, j;
 for (i = 0; i < tracker; i++)
 {
     for (j = i+1; j < tracker; j++)
     {
         //Combines first and last names into 1 name for easy comparison
         strcpy(phonebook[i].totalname, phonebook[i].fName);
         strcpy(phonebook[j].totalname, phonebook[j].fName);
         strcat(phonebook[i].totalname, phonebook[i].lName);
         strcat(phonebook[j].totalname, phonebook[j].lName);
         printf("\nTotal name = %s\nTotal name = %s", phonebook[i].totalname, phonebook[j].totalname); //Done so I can verify it worked correctly
         if (strcmp(phonebook[i].totalname, phonebook[j].totalname) > 0)
         {
            strcpy(temp[i].fName, phonebook[i].fName);
            strcpy(temp[i].lName, phonebook[i].lName);
            temp[i].number = phonebook[i].number;
            temp[i].area = phonebook[i].area;

            strcpy(phonebook[i].fName, phonebook[j].fName);
            strcpy(phonebook[i].lName, phonebook[j].lName);
            phonebook[i].number = phonebook[j].number;
            phonebook[i].area = phonebook[j].area;

            strcpy(phonebook[j].fName, temp[i].fName);
            strcpy(phonebook[j].lName, temp[i].lName);
            phonebook[j].number = temp[i].number;
            phonebook[j].area = temp[i].area;
         }
     }
 }
 printf("\n\nSuccessfully sorted!\n\n");
 }
 }
 else
 printf("\n\nYou need people in the phone book before you can sort it.\n\n");
 }

 -------------------------
 typedef struct PhoneBook
 {
   char fName[20];
   char lName[20];
   char totalname[40];
   float number;
   int area;    
  } phone;
```

Edited to add the structure. And I don't use qsort because we haven't learned about it in class and the TA's are rather strict about not using stuff we haven't learned.

```
void Add(phone *phonebook, int *num_entries)
{    
 int tracker = *num_entries;
 if (tracker == 0)
 {
    printf("\n\nSomething's wrong here\n\n");
 }
 else
 {
      const int newSize = tracker + 1;
      phone *temp = (phone*) realloc(phonebook, (newSize * sizeof(phone)));
      if (temp!=NULL)
      {
         phonebook = temp;
      }
      else
          phonebook = NULL;
 }
 if (phonebook == NULL)
    printf("\n\nOut of memory, can't add more to your phonebook\n\n");
 else
 {
     printf("\n\nEnter the first name: ");
     scanf("%s", phonebook[tracker].fName);
     printf("\nPlease enter the last name: ");
     scanf("%s", phonebook[tracker].lName);
     printf("\nPlease enter the area code: ");
     scanf("%d", &phonebook[tracker].area);
     printf("\nPlease enter the phone number (no dashes allowed): ");
     scanf("%f", &phonebook[tracker].number);
     *num_entries += 1;
     printf("\nContact Added.\n\n");
 }
}
```

Edited again to show the code to add people to the phone book (also broken). After 3-4 entries, it starts placing garbage values for entries.

```
int main()
{
int userInput = 8; //means exit
int num_entries = 1;
phone *phonebook = (phone*) calloc(1 , sizeof(phone));
if (phonebook == NULL)
    printf("\n\nOut of memory\n\n");
else
{
do
{
     system("cls"); 
     printf("Menu: \n");
     printf("1) Add a Contact\n");
     printf("2) Delete a Contact\n");
     printf("3) Display Phone Book\n");
     printf("4) Alphabetically Sort\n");
     printf("5) Find a Contact\n");
     printf("6) Random Contact\n");
     printf("7) Delete All\n");
     printf("8) Exit\n\n");
     scanf(" %d", &userInput);

     switch (userInput)
     {
            case 1: //Add a Friend
                 Add(phonebook, &num_entries);
                 break;
            case 2: //Delete a Friend
                 Delete(phonebook, &num_entries);
                 break;
            case 3: //List all contacts
                 Display(phonebook, &num_entries);
                 break;
            case 4:
                 Sort(phonebook, &num_entries);
                 break;
            case 5:
                 Find(phonebook, &num_entries);
                 break;
            case 6:
                 Random(phonebook, &num_entries);
                 break;
            case 7:
                 DeleteAll(phonebook, &num_entries);
                 break;
            case 8:
                 free(phonebook);
                 break;
     }
     system("PAUSE");  
  }while(userInput != 8);
 }
 return 0;
}
```

Edited to show the calls for each function

Well I can't post photos without more reputation so here's the links:
Photo 1 - Adding 3 contacts works fine: http://s980.photobucket.com/user/valondon/media/C%20Realloc%20Errors/Erroronerealloc_zpsc8228131.png.html?sort=3&o=0
Photo 2 - The phone book after the fourth contact was added: http://s980.photobucket.com/user/valondon/media/C%20Realloc%20Errors/Errorthreerealloc_zps246b76e3.png.html?sort=3&o=2

Comment: You don't show what `phone` type is! And why don't you call `qsort` ?

Comment: Why do you need an array of `temp` -- you only need one temporary phone.

Comment: Edited to add the structure. And I don't use qsort because we haven't learned about it in class and the TA's are rather strict about not using stuff we haven't learned.
___
I'll change it to only 1 temporary phone and see what happens

Comment: It doesn't, it still spits back garbage values with the possibility of crashing.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Problem is with the outer loop.

If you have say 'n' entries in the array to sort, then you have to compare the first entry of the array with remaining 'n-1' entries. After first entry is compared with all 'n-1' entries that means first entry is properly located at its location in sorted array. Now you have left with 'n-1' entries to sort. Now if you want to compare 2nd entry of the array then you have to compare that 2nd entry with remaining 'n-1-1' (only 'n-1' entries left to sort and you have taken 2nd entry to compare with rest of the entries).  this goes on till the end.

In your code you can change the code like below (the loop part):
Note: I have created a temp variable of temp of structure phone.

```
    phone temp;
    for (i = 0; i < tracker - 1; i++)
    {
        for (j = i+1; j <= tracker - 1; j++)
        {
             //Combines first and last names into 1 name for easy comparison
             strcpy(phonebook[i].totalname, phonebook[i].fName);
             strcpy(phonebook[j].totalname, phonebook[j].fName);
             strcat(phonebook[i].totalname, phonebook[i].lName);
             strcat(phonebook[j].totalname, phonebook[j].lName);
             printf("\nTotal name = %s\nTotal name = %s", phonebook[i].totalname, phonebook[j].totalname); //Done so I can verify it worked correctly
             if (strcmp(phonebook[i].totalname, phonebook[j].totalname) > 0)
             {
                 strcpy(temp.fName, phonebook[i].fName);
                 strcpy(temp.lName, phonebook[i].lName);
                 temp.number = phonebook[i].number;
                 temp.area = phonebook[i].area;

                 strcpy(phonebook[i].fName, phonebook[j].fName);
                 strcpy(phonebook[i].lName, phonebook[j].lName);
                 phonebook[i].number = phonebook[j].number;
                 phonebook[i].area = phonebook[j].area;

                 strcpy(phonebook[j].fName, temp.fName);
                 strcpy(phonebook[j].lName, temp.lName);
                 phonebook[j].number = temp.number;
                 phonebook[j].area = temp.area;
             }
         }
     }
     printf("\n\nSuccessfully sorted!\n\n");
 }
```

Comment: That seems to have fixed the sorting issues. However the code I have to add entries to the phonebook now seems to be broken. Could anything that was done here somehow break the other code?

Comment: Hi Ryan, As you are not adding the entries to phonebook in the sort function i don't think there will be any problem with the other part of the code. Could you please give more information on where exactly the code is braking and what is the error it is giving!?

Comment: Added the code to the OP. It breaks after adding 3-4 people to the phone book. It worked perfectly fine last night so I'm confused as to what went wrong.

Comment: how the `Add(phone *phonebook, int *num_entries)` is called!? and i could not find the loop to add entries to phonebook in your ADD() part of the code.

Comment: Edited the OP again to include the calls for all the functions.

Comment: whats the error that its showing!? does the console window closes or it just terminate the program!? If it just terminate the program try to add the print statement at "case 8" in your code so that you can be sure that it is not terminating because of exit!

Comment: There's no error that's showing per say. What happens is that when I try to add more than 3 people to the phone book, it doesn't add them and instead the phone book starts containing garbage values. I'll add a screen shot to the OP

Comment: @Ryan: did the program worked later!? I checked your post now. your code looks to be fine.

Comment: No it didn't. I have no idea what caused the problem. Could it be a compiler issue?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is with your for loops.

In your example, j is equal to i+1 in the second loop. i has a maximum value of tracker - 1, so j can be equal to tracker. This will cause you to overshoot the array, which can trash memory.

Try changing them to:

```
for (i = 0; i < tracker - 1; i++)
{
    for (j = 0; j < tracker - i - 1; j++)
```

The other issue is that in your inner loop, you are using [i] and [j] to index your swaps. If you change every [i] in that loop to [j+1], you'll have a working bubble sort.

Your inner loop ends up as:

```
      phone temp; /* I created a stack variable called temp - saves the need for allocation */

      for (i = 0; i < tracker - 1; i++)
{
    for (j = 0; j < tracker - i - 1; j++)
    {
        //Combines first and last names into 1 name for easy comparison
        strcpy(phonebook[j+1].totalname, phonebook[j+1].fName);
        strcpy(phonebook[j].totalname, phonebook[j].fName);
        strcat(phonebook[j+1].totalname, phonebook[j+1].lName);
        strcat(phonebook[j].totalname, phonebook[j].lName);
        printf("\nTotal name = %s\nTotal name = %s", phonebook[j+1].totalname, phonebook[j].totalname); //Done so I can verify it worked correctly
        if (strcmp(phonebook[j+1].totalname, phonebook[j].totalname) > 0)
        {
            strcpy(temp.fName, phonebook[j+1].fName);
            strcpy(temp.lName, phonebook[j+1].lName);
            temp.number = phonebook[j+1].number;
            temp.area = phonebook[j+1].area;

            strcpy(phonebook[j+1].fName, phonebook[j].fName);
            strcpy(phonebook[j+1].lName, phonebook[j].lName);
            phonebook[j+1].number = phonebook[j].number;
            phonebook[j+1].area = phonebook[j].area;

            strcpy(phonebook[j].fName, temp.fName);
            strcpy(phonebook[j].lName, temp.lName);
            phonebook[j].number = temp.number;
            phonebook[j].area = temp.area;
        }
    }
}
```